# How to run vc++ .exe file where MS Visual Studio is not installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I developed one application in vc++(console) in Visual Studio 2008 . Now, how can I run its .exe where Visual Studio is not installed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like the VC++ 2008 redistributable package - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en

Just ship the package as part of your application installation and deploy it on the target machines.

Comment: Hi Lingvomir...thanks for reply but it is not working even after installing the redistributable package and .net frame work.

Comment: Is it a release build? The redistributable package only installs the release version libraries. You can't run a debug build this way.

Comment: @Kishor Kurmar: "it is not working" doesn't provide any useful info. Explain what happens, them people may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of Visual Studio is to create standalone programs.  As long as the machine you'll run the app on all the DLLs and such that the app requires (and has a compatible .net Framework version installed, if you created a C++/CLI app), the exe file should run just fine.

You should be able to just copy the contents of the output directory (where the .exe is) onto another machine and run it.  You may want to look into creating a setup project / installer, though, if you intend for lots of people to use it.

Comment: Hi Chao...thanks for reply but even after installing .net framework its not opening the console(.exe) application.

Comment: @Kishor Kumar: Define "it's not opening the...application".  Unless you get an error, it ran; it may just not have shown anything.  If you get an error, what is it?